# Android Error: IllegalStateException

Tags: java, android, fragment, bitcoin, illegalstateexception

I am working on a Bitcoin dashboard for Android. The following fragment uses the entered wallet address to display the balance in BTC. When an address is entered, it will add to the listview. When an item in the listview is selected, it will set the edittext to that address.

It is not yet complete, but for now it is throwing an error with the message, "The content of the adapter has changed but ListView did not receive a notification. Make sure the content of your adapter is not modified from a background thread, but only from the UI thread."

I currently have two example addresses in place for testing. If I select one then the other then the first again etc. it works fine. The error appears when I select one, press the button, then select the other.

```
public class WalletFragment extends Fragment {

    ArrayList<String> savedWallets;
    ArrayAdapter<String> listAdapter;
    String newWalletAddress, jsonString, address, balance;
    JSONObject jsonObj, data;
    Double balanceDouble;
    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.####");
    private WalletListener listener;

    public interface WalletListener {
        void onCreateWallet(String newWalletAddress);
    }

    public WalletFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    public static WalletFragment newInstance(ArrayList<String> wallets) {
        WalletFragment fragment = new WalletFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putStringArrayList("savedWallets", wallets);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    public static WalletFragment newInstance(ArrayList<String> wallets, String json) {
        WalletFragment fragment = new WalletFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putStringArrayList("savedWallets", wallets);
        args.putString("jsonString", json);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        if (context instanceof WalletListener) {
            listener = (WalletListener) context;
        }
        else {
            throw new ClassCastException(context.toString()
                    + " must implement MyListFragment.OnItemSelectedListener");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        listener = null;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_wallet, container, false);
        ListView lv = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.walletListView);
        df.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.CEILING);

        final EditText walletAddressEditText = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.walletAddressEditText);
        TextView addressTV = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.walletAddresstextView);
        TextView balanceTV = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.walletBalanceTextView);

        savedWallets = getArguments().getStringArrayList("savedWallets");

        if (savedWallets == null) {
            savedWallets = new ArrayList<>();
        }
        savedWallets.add("198aMn6ZYAczwrE5NvNTUMyJ5qkfy4g3Hi");
        savedWallets.add("1L8meqhMTRpxasdGt8DHSJfscxgHHzvPgk");
        // TODO remove test addresses

        jsonString = getArguments().getString("jsonString");

        if (jsonString != null) {
            try {
                jsonString = getArguments().getString("jsonString");
                jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonString);
                data = new JSONObject(jsonObj.getString("data"));
                balance = data.getString("balance");
                balanceDouble = Double.parseDouble(balance);
                address = data.getString("address");

                String walletAddressText = getResources().getString(R.string.wallet_address, address);
                addressTV.setText(walletAddressText);

                String walletBalanceText = getResources().getString(R.string.wallet_balance, df.format(balanceDouble));
                balanceTV.setText(walletBalanceText);

                // TODO add viewing for other wallet data at some point

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d("TickerException", e.toString());
            }
        }

        listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getActivity(), R.layout.main_list_rows, savedWallets);
        lv.setAdapter(listAdapter);
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
            {
                String address = savedWallets.get(position);
                Log.d("wallet", "Selected: " + address);
                walletAddressEditText.setText(address);
            }
        });

        Button button = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.createWalletButton);
        View.OnClickListener ocl = new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                newWalletAddress = walletAddressEditText.getText().toString();
                if (walletAddressEntryStructuralValidation(newWalletAddress)) {
                    if (newWalletAddress != null) {
                        listener.onCreateWallet(newWalletAddress);
                    }
                    else {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "newWalletAddress is null", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
                else {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Please enter a valid wallet address (length is currently " + newWalletAddress.length() + ").", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        };
        // TODO check if wallet is already on list
        button.setOnClickListener(ocl);

        return v;
    }

    public boolean walletAddressEntryStructuralValidation(String address) {
        return ((address.length() > 25) &&
                (address.length() < 36) && (
                (address.substring(0,1).equals("1") ||
                        (address.substring(0,1).equals("3")))));
    }
    // Wallet addresses are 26-35 alphanumeric characters and begin with 1 or 3

}
```

I believe this is all the relevant code but I will be closely watching this thread if anyone needs to request additional source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That message means that the contents of the adapter (the order of items you see in getItem) changed but notifyDataSetChanged or similar function wasn't called.  When changing the items in your adapter contents (which in this case is the savedWallets array list) you must call one of those functions.

Note:  If you're adding several objects at once, you only need to call it once after all are added/removed.  If you're mutating an object but not adding/removing it, you do not need to call it, but calling it may be the easiest way of doing a redraw.

Comment: I had no intention of changing the contents of the data set, but I was in the process of making the new wallet address entries add to the list; maybe this began working without my knowledge. Am I correct in understanding that the error is thrown because there is a change in the ArrayList of wallet address strings, or could it be something else?

Comment: Yes, the error is thrown because the savedWallets array no longer contains the same items in the same order.  You can add things to this list, but you must call notifyDataSetChanged afterwards before the next redraw.

Comment: I think I have the problem solved, but one more quick question: where should I call this method? I believe it should go in the posted fragment's onCreateView but do you have a more specific placement?